# Is there a way to find the first value of x to a corresponding y in a tuple/ list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples, abaqus

I am working with python 2.7 and want to do some post-processing for Abaqus odb.

I have a tuple which looks like following :

```
tuple_1= ( (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (xfind, ywant), .. (xend, yend) )
```

And I want to find the first corresponding x, xfind, to a given value of y, ywant.
I tried to work with '.index(ywant)' with the aim that it returns xfind, but it wasn't really helpful since I need xfind too...

But maybe it is better to be more specific, as it can be maybe solved by some boolean actions (..?) too:
The x values of the tuples are timesteps and the y values are either 1.0 or 0.0.
I would like to go trough all y values until the value swtiches from 1.0 to 0.0 and then find the corresponding time and use both xfind and ywant in further code.

It isn't a problem for further code to transfer the tuple to a list.

Is there a way to perform this with python 2.7?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice way using `next`:

```
next((x for x, y in tuple_1 if y == 'ywant'), 'not found')
```

**Code**:

```
tuple_1= ( ('x1', 'y1'), ('x2', 'y2'), ('xfind', 'ywant'), ('xend', 'yend') )

print(next((x for x, y in tuple_1 if y == 'ywant'), 'not found'))
# xfind
```

Comment: After refreshing the url I can't find the comments anymore, so I want to ask again, if there's any way, to count the number of elements until xfind? 
I tried it with count, but it won't work with tuples...do you have an idea maybe?

Answer (score 0):

to get the `xwant` and the number of elements untill `xwant` you can use a `dict` comprehension (if you do not have more than 1 `ywant`):

```
tuple_1 = ( ('x1', 'y1'), ('x2', 'y2'), ('xfind', 'ywant'), ('xend', 'yend') )
{y: {'x': x, 'count': i} for i, [x, y] in enumerate(tuple_1)}['ywant']
```

output:

```
{'x': 'xfind', 'count': 2}
```

also, you can use the built-in function [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
next(((i, x) for i, [x, y] in enumerate(tuple_1) if y == 'ywant'), 'not found')
```

output:

```
(2, 'xfind')
```